# Count distinct sql and break by day with timestamp over midnight

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a time series of data that has a `trip_id` and time stamp. I'm trying to write a SQL query to give me the number of unique `trip_id's` that occur on one day.

The problem is that the trip's extend across midnight, as the next day comes the trip is treated as a new distinct value and counted twice using this code `select date(Timestamp), COUNT(DISTINCT trip_id)` . Any help or the appropriate point in the correct direction would be very much appreciated.

Data:

```
trip_id    Timestamp
47585      "2015-11-05 09:22:23"
16935      "2015-11-05 12:34:28"
16935      "2015-11-05 20:40:28"
16935      "2015-11-05 23:09:24"
16935      "2015-11-05 23:21:58"
16935      "2015-11-06 00:22:05"
15434      "2015-11-06 21:23:28"
```

Desired Outcome

```
date             count            
2015-11-05        2
2015-11-06        1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the minimum of the timestamp for each trip:

```
select dte, count(*)
from (select trip_id, min(date_trunc('day', timestamp)) as dte
      from t
      group by trip_id
     ) t
group by dte
order by dte;
```

That is, count the day when the trip begins.

Comment: Have you left off `minimum` in your answer